# Best index(s) for multiple table join and limit

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am trying to create indexes to speed up my query, but according to the EXPLAIN code I am falling short on the last index.

`SELECT *

        FROM (

            table_A AS tbA,

            table_B AS tbB,

            table_C AS tbC,

            table_D AS tbD

        )

        WHERE tbB.id = tbA.id

        AND tbD.x_id = tbA.x_id

        AND tbD.u_id = tbC.u_id

        AND tbB.type =0

        ORDER BY tbA.updated DESC

        LIMIT 25`

Looking at the EXPLAIN result, table_B is the only one not using an index, (and it is scanning 40K rows ~5% of the table), 
According to the 'Extra' section, "Using temporary; Using filesort"

I created an index on table_B ( id, type) but MySQL does not seem to use it.

What am I missing and how can I fully optimise my query?

Thanks

Comment: any reason why left/inner join is not used ?

Comment: truth be told, I don't know how to write a left/inner join on a 4xtable query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare.

```
#Using filesort
    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM
    table_a AS tbA 
    INNER JOIN table_b AS tbB ON (tbA.id=tbB.id)
    INNER JOIN table_d AS tbD ON (tbD.x_id=tbA.x_id)
    INNER JOIN table_c AS tbC ON (tbD.u_id=tbC.u_id)
    WHERE tbB.`type` = 0
    ORDER BY tbA.updated DESC
```

with :

```
#Using temporary; Using filesort
    explain SELECT *
    FROM (
    table_a AS tbA,
    table_b AS tbB,
    table_c AS tbC,
    table_d AS tbD
    )
    WHERE tbB.id = tbA.id
    AND tbD.x_id = tbA.x_id
    AND tbD.u_id = tbC.u_id
    AND tbB.type =0
    ORDER BY tbA.updated DESC
```

Using SELECT * FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id will result in Using temporary.
Also, if updated, x_id , u_id are not indexes/primaries it will have a bad effect on the select, but you need to only add indexes according to your needs. Make sure are aware of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)

You can play with my example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21d2da/3
 ( add/remove the comment on the queries to see the difference )